# What is the ideal of the given ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Determine all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Q}$

The short but annoying question to think. The answer is $\{0,0\}$ and itself (such a trivial problem) which I found in the manual solution section (and it doesn't show its steps or some explanations) , I really don't know how to get it. I have read my textbook but found no information. Please, help.

Comment: i would like to add One more hint from my side, **hint**: if $F$ is field then only ideal of $F$ are $\{0\}$ and $F$ itself. Use this hint with answer given by "@rschwieb sir" :-)

Comment: That's it. There are four ideals?

Comment: So, please point it out

Comment: List four ideals that you had find.

Comment: Each of them has two trivial ideals. So, there are 4 ideals. {0} X Q,  {0,0}, Z7 x Q,  Z7 X {0}

Comment: Yes you where right I had done mistake there are four different ideals. I forget, $\{0\}×\{0\}$. Nice work..

Answer (score 2):

The ideals of $R\times S$ are exactly of the form $I\times J$ where $I\lhd R$ and $J\lhd S$.

The assertion you gave about there being only two ideals is wrong.

Comment: So there are infinite ideals?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy Why not put the random guesses on hold and try to apply what I’ve written?